# multiple select in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search between 2 tables but that field i want to search is foreign key  in other table

my tables are like this:

table 1

```
ID  TitleSR
1   888 
2   999
```

table 2

```
ID  TitleSR
1   11
2   22
3   33
4   44
```

table contain value

```
ID  value
11  italy
22  swiss
888 lilium
999 mount
33  england
```

Comment: can you elaborate with example ? Show what you want to search and what is the expected result

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt,

Comment: what is difference between table 1 and table 2

Comment: union them and select them with a subselect

Comment: @plaidDK thank's a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand you. Try this one:

```
Select *
From table3 as VCT Inner Join
    (Select * From table1
     Union
     Select * From table2) as FGT
On VCT.ID = FGT.TitleSR
Where value = 'italy';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these methods:

**Returns only t1 fields**

> SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 
>   WHERE t1.ID in (SELECT ID FROM Table2);

**Returns ALL fields**

> SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 
>   JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;

If your 'values' exist in a separate table (tblValues), you can use any of these:

**Returns tblValues fields**

> SELECT * FROM tblValues tval 
>   WHERE tval.ID in (SELECT TitleSR FROM Table1);

**returns ALL fields**

> SELECT *
>   FROM (tblValues tval 
>   JOIN Table1 t1 on tval.ID = t1.TitleSR)
>   JOIN Table2 on tval.ID = Table2.TitleSR;